# BootStrap - Form Validation not reseting after form close

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a form using bootstrap form validation, [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation). My form window can be closed, which resets all the input boxes, but if the user triggers the "invalid" validation (red outline and red message) and then closes the re-opens the form window the invalid messages and css are still there.

At the moment I am just removing the "was-validated" class that is attached to my form to reset the validation messages, is there a better way?

Comment: to get the error message what backend language your using? i mean how your validating the input fields?

Comment: if your using php use unset method for ex:- unset($_SESSION($errormsgvariable)). if not please clarify the question

Comment: I don't think I am using backend, the example I followed said it's a client side verification, just to check if the input box is empty or not. 

To build it I am using, HTML,Bootstrap,JS.